# Retaining multiple values sent from form in an array in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, forms

```
   <html>
            <body>
    <form method="post" action="#">
        <h1> AB_NO</h1>
        <input type=text name="excel"> //input values that need to be checked for presence in database.

        <input type=submit name="submit">

        </form>
            <?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
    $host="localhost";
    $user="root";
    $password="";
    $db="green";
    $table="manitable";

    mysql_connect("$host","$user","$password") or die("Cannot Connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db") or die("Cannot select DB!");

    $var=$_POST['excel'];

    $sql="SELECT * FROM manitable WHERE (ab_no = '$var')";

    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $data_item=array();
    $items=array();

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
    print 'Product Exists' ;

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        $data_item['doc_no'] = $row['doc_no'];
        $data_item['ab_no'] = $row['ab_no'];
        $data_item['od_id'] = $row['od_id'];


        $items[] = $data_item;

    }
        print_r($items);

    }
    else {
    print 'Sorry, this Product is not present' ;
    }
    }

    ?>
    </body>
        </html>
```

The above code is the code I am using.

The form field with `name=excel` takes in different strings at a time. On each value entered I want it to be stored in the `$items` array. The value entered in form field is checked if it is present in database. If present it must be stored in the `$items` array along with the other column values. Initially a value is entered in the field and the value along with the corresponding column entries are stored in the items array.

The items array at an index value of 0 will hold the corresponding values from the form value that is sent. Now when a second value is again passed through the form I want it to be stored in the array as a second entry in the items array.

My `manitable` table in database has the following columns:

- `doc_no`
- `ab_no`
- `od_id`

The output is:

```
 Product ExistsArray ( [0] => Array ( [doc_no] => 202344223341312 [ab_no] => SMLP3105153342 [od_id] => ODRD3028479929633865301 ) )
```

I want the new `ab_no` entries which are matched on comparison with db values to be added to the [1], [2] and so on indices of the items array.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use Sessions if you want to store the value after submit.

First start a session if there is none or just leave it like you already have it now.

Recommended way for versions of PHP >= 5.4.0

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
```

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php

For versions of PHP < 5.4.0

```
if(session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}
```

Then store your `$data_item` in the session instead of the `$items` array.

```
$_SESSION['items'][] = $data_item;
$items = $_SESSION['items'];
```

Then you can `print_r()` your $items.

And don't forget to leave your action out of the form like [Sverri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31696024/2078780) said.

Comment: Working now! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Forms that have `action="#"` will not be submitted. The `#` in URLs is called a *fragment*, and are used (among other things) to refer to elements in the document that have `id` attributes on them.

Since you are handling the form in the same file you should just omit the `action` attribute all-together:

```
<form method="post"></form>
```

Comment: That is fine but I really need help in adding the values to the items array and retaining it every time I enter different values from the form. Because the first value that i enter is getting submitted to the items array but a next value that follows is not getting appended to the existing items array. Thanks.